How would I change the font/typeface of the article text in `elfeed`?
I am using elfeed to read blog posts and articles, which is really great. But one problem I run into, is that the typeface for the article itself seems to come from the webpage, and it is not a fixed width font. Hence, the formatting and page breaks and stuff look weird in emacs and makes the articles a little harder to read. Here is an example. You can see the difference between the font one the left and the font on the right side of the image below.

I was hoping that I could actually set the font, or make elfeed use the existing emacs default font, etc. Is there a way to do this?
I tried using the code below, which I found online. But this code does not work for me, as it actually generate some kind of search error that prevents me from looking at content.
Does anyone have a suggestion about how to set the font for the articles in elfeed?
;; Customize elfeed font for text in the show window.
  (setq elfeed-show-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
    (set-face-attribute 'variable-pitch (selected-frame) :font (font-spec :family "Iosevka Nerd Font Mono" :size 18))
    (setq fill-column 120)
    (setq elfeed-show-entry-switch #'my-show-elfeed)))

  (defun my-show-elfeed (buffer)
  (with-current-buffer buffer
    (setq buffer-read-only nil)
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (re-search-forward "\n\n")
    (fill-individual-paragraphs (point) (point-max))
    (setq buffer-read-only t))
  (switch-to-buffer buffer))

